# Prove $f$ is differentiable at $c=0$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $|f(x)| \le x\sqrt{|x|}$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c=0$.

I believe I have to use the limit definition of a derivative but I am unsure of what f(x) is

Comment: You should be able to reason f(0)=0 (why?) and go from there with the definition of the derivative. Also I believe the squeeze theorem might be of use to you.

Comment: I don't know what my f(x) is to be able to explain f(0)=0

Comment: there is no way that $|f(x)| \le x\sqrt{|x|}$ say when $x=-1$,tried to edit but apparently was not accepted. What about $|f(x)| \le |x|\sqrt{|x|}$ ?

Comment: What happens if you plug in zero for x in the condition for f(x)?

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Is correct. There is something wrong with the question. The inequality does not make sense when $x$ is negative.

Comment: your edit was not accepted because that's not the problem I was given to solve

Comment: What they are saying is that your problem doesn't make sense then. If x is negative, you have the absolute value of something being negative.

Comment: if you insist on $|f(x)| \le x\sqrt{|x|}$ then the problem is too easy ... such a function does not exist, so anything you say about it is true ...

Comment: @user196606 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to know the explicit form of $ f $. Simply observe that $ f(0) = 0 $ (which is a very direct consequence of your inequality) and that
\begin{align}
\forall h \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}: \quad
      \left| \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} \right|
& =   \left| \frac{f(h)}{h} \right| \\
&\leq \left| \frac{h \sqrt{|h|}}{h} \right| \\
& =   \sqrt{|h|}.
\end{align}
Then use the Squeeze Theorem as $ h \to 0 $.

Comment: I’m assuming that your inequality should instead be $ |f(x)| \leq |x| \sqrt{|x|} $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, otherwise it wouldn’t make sense for negative values of $ x $.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $f(0) = 0$ by the assumption. Then    $|\frac{f(t) - f(0)}{t}| = |\frac{f(t)}{t}| \leq |\frac{t\sqrt{|t}|}{t}| = |\sqrt{|t|}|$.  Now, the derivative is the limit as $t\to 0$, which exists.